# Angular filter by multiple properties and show if any value is equal to search

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

When using ng-repeat I want to filter object by two values (name and description). I want to filter this array in way if in any key exists value in search it will return it. When I'm trying this `filter:{info:{name:search, description:search}}` the result is when value from search equals in both.

Comment: Kindly make the question more understandable. Do you have a search box and bases upon input there you want to filter the `ng-repeat` values?

Comment: Yes, I have input for search and i want use only one.

Comment: You have a search box and based on it you want to control the values in ng-repeat, right?  'I have input on search part' - I don't get it.

Comment: Yes, I have a search box and based on it I want to control the values.

Comment: is this is what you wanted mate?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so based on what I have been able to understand. Although I am not sure if this is what you wanted, if not let me know and I will delete this answer.

Let's say you have object that has values in this format which you are feeding to `ng-repeat`.

```
  $scope.inputobject = [
    {name: 'xyz', description: 'hadhash'},
    {name: 'uza', description: 'hadhahdh'},
    {name: 'aaa', description: 'hadhahas'}  
  ];
```

This is our HTML part now, add the controller and all, I hope that wont be a problem.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search" ng-model="objectsearch">
<div ng-repeat="x in inputobject | filter:{name:objectsearch}">
<div>
{{x.name}} {{x.lastname}}
</div>
</div>
```

Now filter will only happen based on first input. Cheers!